# Iterator error when accessing context state

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

I get this error for the following code in React Native:

```
Invalid attempt to destructure non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array object must have a [symbol.iterator]() method
```

counter-context.js

```
import React, {useState, createContext} from 'react'

export const CounterContext = createContext();

export const CounterContextProvider = props => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={[count, setCount]}>
      {props.children}
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

counter-display.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { CounterContext, CounterContextProvider } from '../context/counter-context';

export default function Counter() {
    const [count] = useContext(CounterContext);
    
    return (
        <CounterContextProvider>
            <View style={styles.sectionContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{count}</Text>
            </View>
        </CounterContextProvider>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    sectionContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 24,
    }
```

App.js

```
<SafeAreaView>
        <ScrollView
          contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior="automatic"
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View style={styles.body}>
            <Counter/>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

What is the reason? Seems to work in react.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useContext(CounterContext)` call exists in a component that is not a descendant of `<CounterContextProvider>`. The `<CounterContextProvider>` needs to be an ancestor of `<Counter>`, not a descendant.

As for the error message you're getting, it's due to the array destructuring syntax in the assignment statement `const [count] = useContext(CounterContext);` which makes an implicit call to the return value's `[Symbol.iterator]()` method, if it exists. Since there is no provider in scope and the context was created without passing a default value, you're essentially evaluating `const [count] = undefined;`